# Android Bluetooth: Java.IO.IOException: Success - What does it mean?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, logcat, ioexception

Here's a snapshot of my PC with this log message logged in Logcat:

[image: Don't know what it is.]

Anyone knows what this means?

Comment: This is coming from within a native method, so its probably a quirk of the underlying Bluetooth stack. What's the hardware/platform this is actually running on?

Comment: @SimonB Samsung Galaxy Nexus, Android 4.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be something which is widely reported, and I confess its a new one on me! The only thing I can say is that there is certainly some discrepancy in how best to create a `BluetoothSocket` on different devices.  Have a look at this question, it *might* be relevent: [BluetoothServerSocket accept fails and throws an IOException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428820/bluetoothserversocket-accept-fails-and-throws-an-ioexception)

Comment: Even though the IOException that was thrown in the link given is "Connection timed out", it's still irrelevent to this. Like you said, it seems to be not widely reported, and even possible that it's a rare Bluetooth IOException case. I'll try asking the Android OS devs on Google code, and will get back to you.

Comment: [The link here goes to Android Code](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=50216&thanks=50216&ts=1361349209)

Comment: The problem has been solved. It's just an error with networking and multithreading. It causes the Logcat to output the message, `strerror(0)`, which is another meaning for "Success". Everything's fine now.