# Android BluetoothServerSocket's accept() mathos throws IOException

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am using Google's sample Bluetooth chat code with modifications to develop a Bluetooth-chat application. I m getting `IOException` from BluetoothServerSocket's `accept()` method. I don't know why this happens. Can anyone help me out?. I m posting some of my code.. Everytime the flow is going into catch part. I read some answers but can't get any help.

```
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
                if(tmp != null)
                    Log.d("listening", this.getId()+" listening");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "listen() failed", e);
            }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
            setName("AcceptThread");
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;


            // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
            while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                try {
                    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                    // successful connection or an exception

                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                        Log.d("errormsg", e.getMessage());
                        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
                        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(HomepageActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString(HomepageActivity.TOAST, "Remote device didn't accept the connection request");
                        msg.setData(bundle);
                        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                        break;

                }

                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                        switch (mState) {
                        case STATE_LISTEN:
                        case STATE_CONNECTING:
                            Log.d("msg", "socket not null");
                            // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                            connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                            break;
                        case STATE_NONE:
                        case STATE_CONNECTED:
                            // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (D) Log.i(TAG, this.getId()+"END mAcceptThread");
        }
```

**Logcat**

```
08-28 19:34:04.161: E/BluetoothChatService(6449): accept() failed 08-28 19:34:04.161:
 E/BluetoothChatService(6449): java.io.IOException: read failed, 
    socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1 08-28 19:34:04.161: 
E/BluetoothChatService(6449): at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.
    readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:553) 08-28 19:34:04.161: 
E/BluetoothChatService(6449): at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.
    waitSocketSignal(BluetoothSocket.java:530) 08-28 19:34:04.161: 
E/BluetoothChatService(6449): at 
    android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.accept(BluetoothSocket.java:440)
```

Comment: Post the exception you're getting!

Comment: 08-28 19:34:04.161: E/BluetoothChatService(6449): accept() failed
08-28 19:34:04.161: E/BluetoothChatService(6449): java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
08-28 19:34:04.161: E/BluetoothChatService(6449):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:553)
08-28 19:34:04.161: E/BluetoothChatService(6449):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.waitSocketSignal(BluetoothSocket.java:530)
08-28 19:34:04.161: E/BluetoothChatService(6449):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.accept(BluetoothSocket.java:440)

Comment: What device/OS are you using. I have implemented Bluetooth successfully until recently. I'm getting the same error on Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 with 4.4.2. Add your device and OS to your original post.

Comment: This post might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428820/bluetoothserversocket-accept-fails-and-throws-an-ioexception
It seems different Android versions and different devices need to use different sockets.