# Bluetooth not connecting on 4.4.2

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I've got a Bluetooth device that has connected on all versions of Android that I have tried prior to 4.4.2. Now, it's not connecting on the Galaxy Tab 4 or the S3. The Tab 3 connects fine with 4.1.2. The problem seems to occur in the `AcceptThread` while trying to initialize the `BluetoothSocket`. The code I'm using is based off of the chat example in the sdk.

**My Accept code**

```
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    // The local server socket
    private BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
    public boolean successInit = false;

    public AcceptThread() {
        closeAllConnections();          
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

        // Create a new listening server socket
        while(!successInit) {
            try {
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
                successInit= true;
                Log.i("TAG", "Socket Server Created");
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.i("TAG", e.getMessage());
                successInit = false;
            }
        }

        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }
    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
        Log.i("BluetoothComService", String.valueOf(mState));
        while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

                socket = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()                           
                     .getRemoteDevice(getThermMAC())
                     .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID
                     .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));

           //   socket = mmServerSocket.accept();  // here socket might be closed or timeout
                Log.e("BluetoothComService", "No accept Exception");
            }catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
            }
```

`getThermMAC()` above is my method to return the address of the bonded device.

### The errors

In `run()`, if I use

```
socket=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()                           
                     .getRemoteDevice(getThermMAC())
                     .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID
                     .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
```

then I get a `NPE` at line 501 of `BluetoothSocket.java` in the Android framework which is this line

```
int left = b.length;
```

So it would appear that `b` is `null` but it doesn't appear to be after debugging. `b` is a `byte[]` which is sent from my `BluetoothService` class which sends a brand new, initialized `byte[]` from within the `ConnectedThread` just as the sdk example does and as I've been doing on older versions.

If I comment that out and try to use

```
socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
```

which has been working in the past, then I get

```
bt socket is not in listen state
```

So, I don't know how to put it in "listen state" or why it wouldn't be. Has anyone experienced this or know how to workaround it? Or how to keep from getting the `NPE` if I use the first snippet (if that is even correct).

**I found**

When I was getting an `IOException` I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550372/android-bluetoothserversockets-accept-mathos-throws-ioexception) which led me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428820/bluetoothserversocket-accept-fails-and-throws-an-ioexception) but this hasn't gotten me anywhere.

**Notice:** The bounty message says 4.4.4 but it is 4.4.2 on the Tab 4

**Device Errors**

I also notice these Bluetooth errors when I first connect my device to the computer through USB

```
09-05 15:18:03.217: E/BluetoothServiceJni(15148): SOCK FLAG = 0 ***********************
09-05 15:18:13.177: E/BluetoothServiceJni(15148): SOCK FLAG = 0 ***********************
09-05 15:18:13.217: E/BluetoothServiceJni(15148): SOCK FLAG = 0 ***********************
```

but I have not been able to find out what that flag means.

I realize there are known bugs in the BT stack 4.x ([See one of many bug reports](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63056&q=bluetooth%204.3%20unable%20to%20connect&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars))

`minSDK` is currently 10. Though, if I find a working solution then I can work around that.

Comment: Android replaced the Bluetooth stack with Bluedroid in 4.3, and it's a complete facepalm. Broke all sorts of stuff, including **A2DP**. Any chance of bisecting with 4.2 and 4.3 to see if it breaks there?

Comment: @chrylis I'm pretty sure it worked on 4.2 not sure about 4.3, atm

Comment: What type of device are you trying to connect to?

Comment: @bobbyg603 it is a SPP device that we have manufactured for us. Let me know what other information might be helpful. I send it a command and it sends back sensor information.

Comment: You should probably indicate your minSdk in the questio

Comment: @Code-Apprentice done but that really isn't necessarily an issue. If I can get it to work on the Tab 4 with 4.4.2 then I can adjust things to work with that.

Comment: Please check whether you are trying to make a secure connection in connect device

Comment: This happened to me too. Try to reboot your device

Answer (score 1):

Try *this* code, *this* is working android 4.4.2 on nexus 7

```
private boolean refreshDeviceCache(BluetoothGatt gatt){
    try {
        BluetoothGatt localBluetoothGatt = gatt;
        Method localMethod = localBluetoothGatt.getClass().getMethod("refresh", new Class[0]);
        if (localMethod != null) {
           boolean bool = ((Boolean) localMethod.invoke(localBluetoothGatt, new Object[0])).booleanValue();
            return bool;
         }
    } 
    catch (Exception localException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "An exception occured while refreshing device");
    }
    return false;
}


    public boolean connect(final String address) {
           if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
            Log.w(TAG,"BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
                return false;
        }
            // Previously connected device. Try to reconnect.
            if (mBluetoothGatt != null) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
              if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
                    return true;
               } else {
                return false;
               }
        }

        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter
                .getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }

        // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the
        // autoConnect
        // parameter to false.
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(MyApp.getContext(), false, mGattCallback));
        refreshDeviceCache(mBluetoothGatt);
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
        return true;
```

}

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure I can use this as the device I connect to isn't a smart device. But, maybe if you could explain some of this code such as where it is used, it would help.

Comment: Note that `BluetoothGatt` is only available in API 18+. This answer should probably include that information.

Comment: @codeMagic You might want to consider increasing your minSdk.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice see the edit to my question. Just increasing it isn't going to do anything. Increasing it to work with the `BluetoothGatt` class is an option if someone can tell me *why* that would make it work and possibly how it would be used with my current code. As I understand, that is for low energy devices which the device I am trying to connect to is not.

Comment: Please explain how this answer will help the OP.

Comment: I code app for API10 and found same problem. If device not found in 1 attempt then it's not found ever. Until reboot BT (OFF -> ON). Solved this problem by use InsecureBluetooth (reflection socket) and port 29 (no need accept)

Answer (score 0):

I have also used connection steps using the same code but that could work only for Smart Android device.

you can get the BluetoothDevice object of the particular device you want to connect.
after that you can use BluetoothHeadset's connect and disconnect method via reflection to connect to the perticular BluetoothDevice.

```
Class<?> BTHeadset = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothHeadset");
        Method conn = BTHeadset.getMethod("connect", new Class[] {BluetoothDevice.class});
               conn.invoke(BTHeadset, new Object[] {btDev});
```

same code you can use for disconneting a device using disconnect method via reflection.