# Android 4.0 & 4.1 Bluetooth issues. Detect broken comms & dropping pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluez, spp

**Hey All**,

I understand that Android's bluetooth stack(bluez) was replaced on 4.2. Even though they might have fixed a lot of the previous issues, due to a need to support older versions, i still need to battle with them.

I would **appreciate** tremendously if someone have dealt with this issues before and could shed some light.

### **Issue #1** - Unable to detect broken **comms** (4.0 & 4.1 Android, Bluez bluetooth stack)

The bluetooth app connects to our own **custom SPP device** ( we use the standard **UUID** ). It uses a bluetooth service that runs on it's own process. It's required that this app runs for several hours doing bluetooth work.

During **power-save / screen lock**, the app is kept **alive** while data is coming in through **bluetooth radio**, and also i check periodically with a set alarms, where i request CPU time to reconnect & keep doing work (if necessary)

Now; the system is working fine most of the time, but, in some rare situations when the **screen** is **locked** and in **power-save** mode, for reasons i don't understand, upon **writing** into the **output-stream** (bluetooth socket) , everything seems to go through without a broken connection being detected. The spp device still states that connection & pairing is valid but receives nothing.

On the Android side, the logs show a native call to **BluetoothSocket.cpp::writeNative** (assuming it's directly related to the **bluez** bluetooth stack) that just seems to write the bytes correctly onto the bluetooth radio without reporting any sort of error.

code piece that writes into output stream :

```
public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                Log.d(LOGGER.TAG_BLUETOOTH," bluetooth bytes to write : "+bytes);
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
                mmOutStream.flush();
                Log.d(LOGGER.TAG_BLUETOOTH," bluetooth bytes written : "+bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

logcat :

> D/com.our.app.bluetooth( 8711):  bytes sending : [B@41e0bcf8
>
> D/com.our.app.bluetooth( 8711):  bluetooth bytes to write :[B@41e0bcf8
>
> **V/BluetoothSocket.cpp( 8711): writeNative**
>
> D/com.our.app.bluetooth( 8711):  bluetooth bytes written :[B@41e0bcf8

**Questions** - Is it correct to assume that, apart from application level checking&heartbeats, broken comms should be detected upon socket I/O operations like in this case? Or could the bluetooth radio just go down during power-save ?

### **Issue #2** - Sudden drop from pairing list.

In Android 4.0 & 4.1, devices in some cases, get unexplainably **dropped** from the **pairing** list. Even this is rare and somewhat only in some particular devices... it's a case where prevents the phone to be re-paired and connected easily.

I do notice that the **SPP** device pairs correctly , but sometimes, the android devices displays the message "Unable to pair to device X, incorrect PIN or Password" .

Note : For android versions < 4.2 we do use insecure comms ( **createInsecureRfcommSocket**, due to other android connection issues for this versions ).

**Questions** - How often should this PIN / Password be refreshed during an session?

This could very well be a bug in our SPP device, but on the off chance that is not, any ideas ?

**Thanks a million**.

Comment: You need to refresh cache look here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25758193/3970250 but I just use insecureSocket on all version

Answer (score 1):

This is working android 4.4.2 on nexus 7

```
private boolean refreshDeviceCache(BluetoothGatt gatt){
try {
    BluetoothGatt localBluetoothGatt = gatt;
    Method localMethod = localBluetoothGatt.getClass().getMethod("refresh", new Class[0]);
    if (localMethod != null) {
       boolean bool = ((Boolean) localMethod.invoke(localBluetoothGatt, new Object[0])).booleanValue();
        return bool;
     }
} 
catch (Exception localException) {
    Log.e(TAG, "An exception occured while refreshing device");
}
return false;}


public boolean connect(final String address) {
       if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
        Log.w(TAG,"BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return false;
    }
        // Previously connected device. Try to reconnect.
        if (mBluetoothGatt != null) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
          if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
                return true;
           } else {
            return false;
           }
    }

    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter
            .getRemoteDevice(address);
    if (device == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
        return false;
    }

    // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the
    // autoConnect
    // parameter to false.
    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(MyApp.getContext(), false, mGattCallback));
    refreshDeviceCache(mBluetoothGatt);
    Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
    return true;
```