# Webservice call from android says permission denied

Tags: android, .net, web-services

I have a web service in .net and I call it from android in localhost. It is to show a string in emulator display but it's not working. It shows access denied in the emulator.

SoapTestActivity.java

```
package com.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.ksoap2.*;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.*;



public class SoapTestActivity extends Activity {
    TextView result;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        final String NAMESPACE = "http://sample.com/";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "SayHello";    
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://sample.com/SayHello";
        final String URL = "http://192.168.1.108/WebService1/Service1.asmx";

        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);            
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            String resultValue = response.toString();

            result.setText(resultValue);           
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            result.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.sample.SoapTestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

the url shown i the firefox browser is

```
http://localhost:5460/Service1.asmx
```

Comment: no error is there. app is running but , emulator displays "permission denied"

Comment: have you set internet permission in manifest file ?

Comment: dont know exactly but look like response is from server (as you caught exception and display it in textview). so check if need to grant permission at server side to call Webservice

Comment: yes.. is there any changes in URL i have to make while running in localhost

Answer (score 0):

please change url  192.168.1.108 to 10.0.2.2:80

After changing this, u will get data on your Emulator

please refer http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses for more reference.

Comment: i add 10.0.2.2.15 and it displayed transport endpoint is not connected

Comment: may be you are missing the Internet Permission in your Manifest file or refer <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289588/android-java-io-ioexception-transport-endpoint-is-not-connected> for more reference.